# Как заменить 0 пробелом при конвертации сообщения, состоящее из чисел, буквами, соответствующими по нумерации алфавита?

Tags: c#, winforms

Я пытаюсь конвертировать сообщение,я исключил все знаки препинания, но надо добавить пробел, допустим я пишу слово - "а а", при конвертации выходит - "1 0 1", пробел считает он как 0, и я хочу чтоб при обратной конвертации он вывел сообщение - "а а", а получается - "аЯа". Пишу код на C#. И я реализовываю алгоритм шифрования Эль-Гамаля.
Заранее спасибо.
Вот мой код:

```
private string ConvertToString(BigInteger[] values)
    {
        string output = "";
        string output2 = "";
        StringBuilder message = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (BigInteger value in values)
        {
            // Преобразование числового значения в символ
            char letter = (char)('а' + (value - 1));
            message.Append(letter);
            output = message.ToString();
            output2 = output.Replace("0", " ");
        }
        //return message.ToString();
        return output2;
    }
```

это метод, который конвертирует числа в буквы.
и код кнопки, в котором все происходит:

```
string num_v = dec_mes.Text;
        string[] tokens = num_v.Split(' ');
        BigInteger[] number_let = tokens.Select(BigInteger.Parse).ToArray();
        string decryptedMessage = ConvertToString(number_let);
        encrypt_mes.Text = decryptedMessage;
```

dec_mes - это мой textbox.
скрин, как я шифрую данные:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
и скрин, как все это выходит:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Не нужно менять 0 на пробел внутри цикла, соберите все цифры вместе, а потом уже вне цикла можете заменять нули на пробелы.

```
private string ConvertToString(BigInteger[] values)
{
    StringBuilder message = new StringBuilder();

    foreach (BigInteger value in values)
    {
        char letter = (char)('а' + (value - 1));
        message.Append(letter);
    }

    string output = message.ToString();
    string output2 = output.Replace("0", " ");
    return output2;
}
```

Comment: не выходит все равно

Comment: Дайте ссылку на реп

Comment: https://github.com/Vladosik1500/EL-Gamal.git

Comment: надеюсь поймешь что там к чему, я реализую полностью функционал приложения, после наведу порядок в коде

Comment: Закиньте нормально проект в реп через гит. У вас в репозитории файл с бинарным кодом.

Comment: https://github.com/Vladosik1500/Crypt.git

Comment: у меня все норм запускается не знаю почему у вас не выходит но щас бех архива кинул

Comment: Я не смог найти ошибку, но я так предполагаю что ошибка вызвана каким-то из алгоритмов, или неверной кодировкой. Также посмотрите что и как вы передаете в методы шифрования/расшифровки. Используйте точки остановки в методах которые могут вызывать подозрения, может в один из них вы передаете неверные аргументы.

Comment: в общем я немного схитрил и поставил замену уже Я на пробел то я не знаю как иначе делать расшифровку сообщения